# xcodebuild error "binaries with multiple platforms are not supported" while generating xcframework library

Tags: ios, xcode, binary, frameworks, xcframework

I'm trying to generate xcframework file from the MyFramework.framework file.

I'm running the following command:

> xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "MyFramework.framework"
> -output "MyFramework.xcframework"

After that I get this error:

> error: binaries with multiple platforms are not supported
> '/Users/nicco/myFramework/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework'

What is the problem with it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This command does not support multi-platform binaries. You should create an archive for each platform.

> Create an archive of the framework or library for each platform you
> wish to support.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev544efab96

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding between platform and architecture, though. You can put fat binaries into an xcframework just fine. You just can't have multiple platforms (e.g. macOS and iOS) in the same fat binary. In fact, you can't include multiple arches for the same platform either. You'll get an error saying the platform already exists in the xcframework.